# How to search double quotes in fulltext search in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, full-text-search, containstable

I have double quotes in my Keyword. How can I search this in my fulltext search query.
I have this query

```
SELECT  top 10 K.[KEY], 10, K.[RANK]
FROM    CONTAINSTABLE(ProductKeywords, Keywords, '("19*") AND ( "<Cat>5" OR "<Cat>30" OR "<Cat>398" ) AND NOT "<Blocked>"' ) AS k
```

It works fine but when i have double quotes in my keyword like

```
SELECT  top 10 K.[KEY], 10, K.[RANK]
FROM    CONTAINSTABLE(ProductKeywords, Keywords, '("19"*") AND ( "<Cat>5" OR "<Cat>30" OR "<Cat>398" ) AND NOT "<Blocked>"' ) AS k
```

it gives this error

```
Msg 7630, Level 15, State 3, Line 1
Syntax error near '*' in the full-text search condition '("19"*") AND ( "<Cat>5" OR "<Cat>30" OR "<Cat>398" ) AND NOT "<Blocked>"'.
```

Comment: try to escape the double quotes with \  e.g. '\"'

Answer (score 1):

To escape double quotes, just double them, like for example

```
SELECT * FROM Tbl WHERE Contains(name, '""quoted""')
```

Answer (score 0):

[How do you escape double quotes inside a SQL fulltext 'contains' function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886011/how-do-you-escape-double-quotes-inside-a-sql-fulltext-contains-function)

```
SELECT TOP 10
    K.[KEY]
  , 10
  , K.[RANK]
FROM
    CONTAINSTABLE(ProductKeywords, Keywords, '("19*") AND ( "<Cat>5" OR "<Cat>30" OR "<Cat>398" ) AND NOT "<Blocked>"')
    AND Keywords LIKE '19"%'
    AS k
```