# TSQL CONTAINSTABLE and wildcard

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, containstable

I'm running a TSQL query that uses a CONTAINSTABLE-statement like this one

```
CONTAINSTABLE(<Table A>, <TargetColumn>, '01100011')
```

which gives me the correct results. However, If I use

```
CONTAINSTABLE(<Table A>, <TargetColumn>, '0110001*')
```

instead, I get 0 result. Can someone please explain to my why ? AFAIK wildcards are supported like this.

This is on MSSQL Server 2008R2

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Could you please share the result of your first statement `'01100011'`

A `*` acts as a `wildcard` and when you give the * after the `'01100011*'` its looks for the value `01100011` followed by any other character.

Comment: The result are 2 rows from <Table A>  that have excaclty '01100011' in <TargetColumn>. I don't get why they are not found by the second statement, where the last 1 was replaced by * (which in my case should result in at lease the same result set).

Comment: Try `CONTAINSTABLE(.., .., '"0110001*"')` (mind the double quotes), per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/query-with-full-text-search#Prefix_Term).

Comment: @Dave please try as advised by Jeroen..

Comment: Works fine, thanks a lot. Is there a way of escaping ' or " within the term to search for ? I have use cases where both are beeing used within the search input,  e.g people searching for terms like 2" diameter

Comment: @Dave: escaping will do you no good since full-text search [doesn't index punctuation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2886011/). (One of the answer suggests disabling the stoplist, but I have no idea if that works.) In any case, that's a different question altogether.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Jeroen's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45586596/tsql-containstable-and-wildcard#comment78138509_45586596), you need to surround your search term with double quotes (within the single quotes).

[The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/query-with-full-text-search#Prefix_Term) gives the example `CONTAINS (Description, '"top*"' )` then says

> If the text and asterisk are not delimited by double quotation marks, as in `CONTAINS (DESCRIPTION, 'top')`, full-text search does not consider the asterisk to be a wildcard.

In your case, `CONTAINSTABLE(<Table A>, <TargetColumn>, '"0110001*"')` should work as you expected.