# SQL Server using LIKE to search column firstname for " " characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-like

I am trying to query a database table to return all records where the firstname column contains the characters `" "`.

For example `Lars-Erik "Molle"`.

I tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM [bgtest].[dbo].[cuscon] WHERE firstname LIKE '%Lars-Erik%'
```

and that returned the record this was just me making sure I was doing it right then I replace the `Lars-Erik` with `""` and ofcourse as it will now look like `'%""%'` it doesn't like it and returns nothing.

Any ideas I've tried CONTAINS and LIKE and can't figure out a way to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escape double quotes in SQL 2005/2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387198/escape-double-quotes-in-sql-2005-2008)

Comment: `CONTAINS` only works on full-text indexed columns containing character-based data types so if your column isn't indexed it won't work for you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like you need query something like:

```
SELECT * FROM [bgtest].[dbo].[cuscon] WHERE firstname LIKE '%"%"%'
```

Because `%""%` will search for two subsequent `"` characters only.

Comment: You sir are a legend. Thanks very much for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM [bgtest].[dbo].[cuscon] WHERE firstname LIKE '%"%'
```